# Cross-Platform Logging

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows

I'm writing an application in `C#.NET` and would like to implement logging. I've never done this before, so if this is a stupid question - bear with me.

The application will be written in `C#`, but will ultimately be deployed on `Windows/iOS/Android`. When choosing a logging framework, *is it necessary to choose one that supports these platforms?* Or, *am I free to choose a framework based on what works for me?*

Essentially, will this framework, being used in my application to either write text to `database` or `file`, need to use the OS it's installed on, or just my code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to check the platform support first before choosing a library.

PS. NLog 4.3 support all those three platforms.